# Do I need to keep my EC2 and RDS instances running on AWS to have my website available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-deployment, amazon-rds

I have recently started getting to know how to use AWS free tier to run a web application, but there are so many information out there that I can't digest all at once! As I've learned so far, we need an RDS instance to have the database on the server, and a EC2 instance to be able to transfer files to the server. If I keep the instances running, I will have to pay for it, and if I stop them, what will happen to my website?!
I need help to understand if I need to keep those instances running all the time.

Comment: Under free tier you get 750 hours of EC2 and RDS usage. So using t2.micro instances wouldn't incur any charges on your account. You can keep them running for entire duration.

Comment: Adding to what @KiranMore says; 750hours for Linux boxes and additional 750 hours for Windows machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You of course need to keep your web server running to serve your website.  How else would users reach it?  Yes, you have to pay for it every minute that it runs, that's how cloud computing works. If you shut it down, your website will become unreachable until you turn it back on.
2. You do not need an RDS instance.  It's much easier to get up and running and is better design, but for a small site, there is no reason you can't just install mySQL on your ec2 box and access it locally.  EC2 is just a server box, you can install whatever you want on it.